# exposing services to a static address

Tags: gcloud, google-kubernetes-engine

Hi I am trying to expose a containerized application using google kubernetes engine, I deployed my services ( backend  and frontend) and I am able to access to them via

http://[external-Ip]:port

but every time I rexpose my service after modifcation the external Ip change.

My questions are:

-what is the next step after deploying the services ( get a staic adress)
how can I connect my backend and my frontend service?

-How to expose the services into static adress ( I do not want my adress changing every time I rebuild and rexpose my services)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following config for your needs.

Publishing services - service types

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/

Comment: Lana.G, sorry about that, i modified.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `Ingress` or `LoadBalancer` `Service`?

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer#step_5_optional_configuring_a_static_ip_address

Comment: I exposed my services as LoadBalancer. I did not use Ingress. Is it a good idea to use ingress instead?

Answer (score 0):

After the update 1.1, kubernetes support externalIPs, you can setup a static IP . it already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32266053/how-to-specify-static-ip-address-for-kubernetes-load-balancer):

After you Deployment, wait until you've an external IP, when you run kubectl get svc, and look up that IP in the [list](https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/networking/addresses/list) on that page and change it from Ephemeral to Static in that way you can [promote your Ephemeral IP to a Static IP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#promote_ephemeral_ip).

As well you can use a gcloud command to do :

```
gcloud compute addresses create [ADDRESS_NAME] \
    --addresses [IP_ADDRESS] --region [REGION]
where:

[ADDRESS_NAME] is the name you want to call this address.
[IP_ADDRESS] is the IP address you want to promote.
[REGION] is the region the IP address belongs to.
```