# How to set HTTPS as default on GKE Ingress-gce

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I currently have a working Frontend and Backend nodeports with an Ingress service setup with GKE's Google-managed certificates.

However, my issue is that by default **when a user goes to samplesite.com, it uses http as default.** This means that the user needs to specifically type in the browser https://samplesite.com in order to get the https version of my website.

**How do I properly disable http on GKE ingress, or how do I redirect all my traffic to https?** I understand that this can be forcefully done in my backend code as well but I want to separate concerns and handle this in my Kubernetes setup.

Here is my ingress.yaml file:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: frontend-node-service
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: frontend
  ports:
  - port: 5000
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: backend-node-service
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: backend
  ports:
  - port: 8081
    targetPort: 9229
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: samplesite-ingress-frontend
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "samplesite-static-ip"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: samplesite-ssl
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: frontend-node-service
    servicePort: 5000
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: samplesite-ingress-backend
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "samplesite-backend-ip"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: samplesite-api-ssl
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: backend-node-service
    servicePort: 8081
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Currently `GKE` Ingress does not support out of the box `HTTP`->`HTTPS` redirect.**

There is an ongoing Feature Request for it here:

- *[Issuetracker.google.com: Issues: Redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS when using the HTTP(S) Load Balancer](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35904733)*

There are some **workarounds** for it:

- Use different `Ingress` controller like `nginx-ingress`.
- Create a `HTTP`->`HTTPS` redirection in `GCP` Cloud Console.

---

> How do I properly disable http on GKE ingress, or how do I redirect all my traffic to https?

To disable `HTTP` on `GKE` you can use following annotation:

- `kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"`

This annotation will:

- Allow traffic only on port: `443 (HTTPS)`.
- Deny traffic on port: `80 (HTTP)` resulting in error code: `404`.

---

Focusing on previously mentioned workarounds:

#### Use different `Ingress` controller like `nginx-ingress`

One of the ways to have the `HTTP`->`HTTPS` redirection is to use `nginx-ingress`. You can deploy it with official documentation:

- *[Kubernetes.github.io: Ingress-nginx: Deploy: GCE-GKE](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#gce-gke)*

This `Ingress` controller will create a service of type `LoadBalancer` which will be the entry point for your traffic. `Ingress` objects will respond on `LoadBalancer IP`. You can download the manifest from installation part and modify it to support the static IP you have requested in `GCP`. More reference can be found here:

- *[Stackoverflow.com: How to specify static IP address for Kubernetes load balancer?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33830507/12257134)*

You will need to provide your own certificates or use tools like `cert-manager` to have `HTTPS` traffic as the annotation: `networking.gke.io/managed-certificates` will not work with `nginx-ingress`.

I used this `YAML` definition and without any other annotations I was always redirected to the `HTTPS`:

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx" # IMPORTANT
spec:
  tls: # HTTPS PART
  - secretName: ssl-certificate # SELF PROVIDED CERT NAME
  rules:
  - host:
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: hello-service
          servicePort: hello-port
```

---

#### Create a `HTTP`->`HTTPS` redirection in `GCP` Cloud Console.

There is also an option to **manually** create a redirection rule for your `Ingress` resource. You will need to follow official documentation:

- *[Cloud.google.com: Load Balancing: Docs: HTTPS: Setting up HTTP -> HTTPS Redirect](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-http-https-redirect#setting_up_the_http_load_balancer)*

Using the part of above documentation, you will need to create a `HTTP` LoadBalancer responding on the same IP as your `Ingress` resource (reserved static IP) redirecting traffic to `HTTPS`.

> Disclaimer!
>
> Your `Ingress` resource will need to have following annotation:
>
> - `kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"`
>
> Lack there of will result in forbidding you to create a redirection mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough options I can go about this! But really, this is quite shocking that this kind of very basic feature has since not yet been implemented.

Comment: @Raven think now it has https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-features#ssl

Comment: Thanks @GridcellCoder! Probably a new update. Not sure if I've read that before.