# How to redirect from http to https automatically in kubernetes_ingress_v1 with Google compute cloud?

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine, terraform-provider-gcp

I am using terraform to deploy a kube cluster to Google Kubernetes Engine.

Here is my ingress config - both http and https are working but I want http to auto redirect to https

```
resource "kubernetes_ingress_v1" "ingress" {
  wait_for_load_balancer = true
  metadata {
    name = "ingress"
  }
  spec {
    default_backend {
      service {
        name = kubernetes_service.frontend_service.metadata[0].name
        port {
          number = 80
        }
      }
    }
    rule {
      http {
        path {
          backend {
            service {
              name = kubernetes_service.api_service.metadata[0].name
              port {
                number = 80
              }
            }
          }
          path = "/api/*"
        }

        path {
          backend {
            service {
              name = kubernetes_service.api_service.metadata[0].name
              port {
                number = 80
              }
            }
          }
          path = "/api"
        }
      }
    }
    tls {

      secret_name = "tls-secret"
    }
  }
  depends_on = [kubernetes_secret_v1.tls-secret, kubernetes_service.frontend_service, kubernetes_service.api_service]
}
```

How can I configure the ingress to auto redirect from http to https?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked for me - I got my hints from https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-kubernetes/issues/1326#issuecomment-910374103

```
resource "kubectl_manifest" "app-frontend-config" {
  wait_for_rollout = true
  yaml_body = yamlencode({
    apiVersion = "networking.gke.io/v1beta1"
    kind       = "FrontendConfig"
    metadata = {
      name = "ingress-fc"
    }
    spec = {
      redirectToHttps = {
        enabled = true
      }
    }
  })
}



resource "kubernetes_ingress_v1" "ingress" {
  wait_for_load_balancer = true
  metadata {
    name = "ingress"
    annotations = {
      "networking.gke.io/v1beta1.FrontendConfig"         = kubectl_manifest.app-frontend-config.name
    }

  }
  spec {
    default_backend {
      service {
        name = kubernetes_service.frontend_service.metadata[0].name
        port {
          number = 80
        }
      }
    }
    rule {
      http {
        path {
          backend {
            service {
              name = kubernetes_service.api_service.metadata[0].name
              port {
                number = 80
              }
            }
          }
          path = "/api/*"
        }

        path {
          backend {
            service {
              name = kubernetes_service.api_service.metadata[0].name
              port {
                number = 80
              }
            }
          }
          path = "/api"
        }
      }
    }
    tls {

      secret_name = "tls-secret"
    }
  }
  depends_on = [kubernetes_secret_v1.tls-secret, kubernetes_service.frontend_service, kubernetes_service.api_service]
}
```

You need an additional module in your `terraform` block

```
   
    kubectl = {
      source  = "gavinbunney/kubectl"
      version = ">= 1.14.0"
    }
```

Do not forget to initialise the kubectl provider

```
provider "kubectl" {
  host                   = "https://${google_container_cluster.primary.endpoint}"
  token                  = data.google_client_config.default.access_token
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(google_container_cluster.primary.master_auth[0].cluster_ca_certificate)
  load_config_file       = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to have the HTTP->HTTPS redirection is to use nginx-ingress. You can deploy it with official [documentation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#gce-gke).

This Ingress controller will create a service of type LoadBalancer which will be the entry point for your traffic. Ingress objects will respond on LoadBalancer IP. You can download the manifest from the installation part and modify it to support the static IP you have requested in GCP.

You will need to provide your own certificates or use tools like `cert-manager` to have HTTPS traffic as the annotation: `networking.gke.io/managed-certificates` will not work `with nginx-ingress.`

Use this YAML definition and without any other annotations I was always redirected to the HTTPS:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx" # IMPORTANT
spec:
  tls: # HTTPS PART
  - secretName: ssl-certificate # SELF PROVIDED CERT NAME
  rules:
  - host:
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: hello-service
          servicePort: hello-port
```

Refer to the [stackpost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63324514/how-to-set-https-as-default-on-gke-ingress-gce/63344422#63344422) for more information and there is also a Feature Request for it [here](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/35904733)

Comment: I have not written any yaml files so far. I am doing everything to terraform - will I need to write yaml and deploy this ingress?

Comment: Yes, you need to write yaml and deploy ingress