# Generating self-signed certificates for Kubernetes pods and services

Tags: kubernetes, ssl

I want to create a SSL certificate for one or more Kubernetes pods or services. I can generate a SSL certificate for them by specifying its IP address for it. However, these IP addresses change. In this case, it's for local access only, no Ingress is desired.

There is the possibility to set a static ip address for a service, as specified in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33830507/2989034). However, is this the only way? What am I missing here? Can't I create a certificate being valid to the whole cluster?

Comment: Why can't you create a cert for the FQDN of the service?

Comment: Is this accessible from outside the cluster (my VM, where the Kubernetes cluster is on. not outside the VM)?